# Help me to solve the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} \Big[\Big( \frac 1 n\Big)^n+\Big(\frac 2 n\Big)^n + \dots +\Big(\frac n n\Big)^n\Big]=\dots $

Tags: limits

Help me with this limit to infinity question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jo52z.jpg)

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \Big[\Big( \frac 1 n\Big)^n+\Big(\frac 2 n\Big)^n + \dots +\Big(\frac n n\Big)^n\Big]=\dots $$

Comment: no...........................................

Comment: i tried to simplify it to lim n to infinity (( 1ⁿ+2ⁿ+..+nⁿ)/nⁿ). then i don't know what else to do. can you give some clue?

Comment: Here is a hint $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} (1-\frac {x}{n})^n = e^{-x}$  Can you get the terms in your limit above to look like the one I have just given you?

Comment: i got ((n-1)/n))^n = (1 - 1/n)^n

Comment: It is certainly at least 1.

Comment: This is one of the toughest limits in the site, which requires tools that aren't usually available in basic limits theory (e.g., Stolz theorem or whatever else). This question doesn't deserve to be closed.

Comment: Not that tough if I can solve it:)

Comment: This question lacks context / attempts and I am pretty sure it is an exact duplicate. May I invoke the help of MSE users to locate it faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boy good thing I put in that false answer ! This way I can still solve the problem even after its closes. LOOPHOLE !

Ok so the limit is

$$x=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \sum\limits_{k=0}^n \left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)^n$$ now if we just take the first $k$ terms as a lower bound be get

$$1+\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n+\cdots +\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)^n\leq x$$

And taking the limit with $k$ fixed gives

$$1+\frac{1}{e}+\cdots +\frac{1}{e^k}\leq x$$

On the other hand $y_n=\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)^n$ is an increasing sequence with $k$ fixed (I checked it with Bernoulli's inequality). So

$$\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)^n\leq \frac{1}{e^k}$$ and thus

$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{e^k}$$ is an upper bound.

So the limit is 
$$\frac{e}{e-1}$$

Comment: thanks a lot !!

Comment: Hey, my pleasure.

Comment: The sum of the last two terms is $1+((n-1)/n)^n = 1+(1-1/n)^n \approx 1+1/e$, so this answer can not be correct. See mine.

Comment: Stolz theorem does not apply since the denominator is not a sum.

Comment: @martycohen What? S-C is about sequences. The problem here is SC was misapplied.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus You've applied SC incorrectly.

Comment: Ok I edited to give a correct proof.

Answer (score 0):

If $k$ is small compared with $n$,
$(\frac{n-k}{n})^n
=(1-k/n)^n
\approx e^{-k}
$.

So the sum of the
last $k$ terms is about
$\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} e^{-j}
=\dfrac{1-e^{-k}}{1-e^{-1}}
\approx \dfrac1{1-1/e}
$
for large $k$.

Since
$-\ln(1-x) > x$,
$1-x < e^{-x}
$
so
$1-k/n < e^{-k/n}$
or
$(1-k/n)^n < e^{-k}$.

Therefore
the sum of the terms
after the $k$-th is
$\sum_{j=k}^{n}(1-j/n)^n 
\lt \sum_{j=k}^{n-1} e^{-j}
=\dfrac{e^{-k}-e^{-n}}{1-e^{-1}}
\lt \dfrac{e^{-k}}{1-1/e}
\to 0
$
for large $k$.

Therefore,
and I think this can be made
rigorous,
the sum is
$\dfrac1{1-1/e}
\approx  1.5819767068693265$.

Wolfy seems to agree.

Comment: so what is the correct answer? is it 1 or 1/(1 - 1/e) ?

Comment: See my comment.

Comment: If you think that it is correct, it is polite to accept the answer.